# Server-side email already exist validation in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form and fields are Name, Email, Password. Client-side validation is working perfectly. I am working on server-side validation.

I am getting the issue on else part. For testing, I  added `echo $email` and I am getting the email id. Now that email id will check in the database is exists or not. If exist the display the error if not existing the display the not exist.

```
if(condition){}
elseif(condition){}
elseif(condition){}
elseif(condition){}
else{
    echo $email; // here I am able to display the email id

    $sql_check_email="SELECT email FROM register WHERE email =?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_check_email);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($email);
    $rows = $stmt->fetch();
    $total_rows = count($rows);
    if( $total_rows > 0 ){
        $_SESSION['email_error']= 'This email is alredy register with us';
        header('location:register');
    }else{
        echo $email;// why my email id not displaying here?
        echo $name;
        echo $password;
        echo $date_of_added;
        echo"Not exist";
    }
```

Comment: It will be good for me if share the reason for downvote so that I will not repeat same in  the future

Comment: `$email` will be reset to the result of the query, and obviously in the else there was no match found on the database... or you would not be in the else

Comment: you didn't store the result, if any. Edit: Consult the duplicates that this was closed with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your issue is:

```
$stmt->bind_result($email);
```

That line replaces variable with query result.
Just use another variable for results.

You also use `fetch` result wrong, it returns just `true/false/null` value of fetch state. Use `bind_result` binded variable to get your results.

Comment: In the else .... there is no email set as obviously it was not found on the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly, doesn't `bind_param` that  work?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I tried    $stmt->bind_result($email_1); and I got my email in else part. @vp_arth, Can you assist me what's wrong in the fetch result?

Comment: `$stmt->bind_result($email); $rows = $stmt->fetch();` you bind and fetch the result of your query. If no matching row is found you are binding NOTHING to `$email`

Comment: See [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). You can use returned value as a flag there was data, but not as fetched dataset. Fetched dataset will be in the `bind_result` variables.

Comment: Thanks for the information @vp_arth, and RiggsFolly. Upvote from my side to notice the error.